# What hypothesis testing for comparing two categorical distributions?

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, categorical-data, contingency-tables

What statistical test do I need to use to test for a significant difference in the distributions of two different categorical variables?

As an example, I need to test whether the distribution of a categorical variable (Let's say different types of houses in a particular village) has changed over the year. The first variable is the distribution (frequency table) of housing types at the beginning of the year, the second variable is the distribution of housing types at the end of the year. Records are anonymous, so I can't pair the two sets. The two sets may be of unequal size.

Answer (score 2):

The standard test for frequency tables is the [$\chi^2$ test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_test). You'll find it in R as `chisq.test` and in nearly every software that implements the basic statistical methods.